# Django Introduce a foreign key from a model CharField

Tags: django, sqlite, model

I have migrated over 10,000 records from my old mySQL database to Django/sqlite. In my old mysql schema's Song table, the artist field was not a 1 to many field but was just a mysql `varchar` field.  In my new Django model, I converted the artist field to a `ForeignKey` and used temp_artist to temporarily store the artist's name from the old database.

How do I create each Song instance's artist foreignkey based on the temp_artist field? I'm assuming I should use the manager's `get_or_create` method but where and how do I write the code?

my model below:

```
class Artist (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Song (models.Model):    
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Artist")
    temp_artist = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Title")
    duration = models.DurationField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Duration")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have a usable foreign key at the moment you would have to dig down to raw_sql. If you were still on mysql you could have used the UPDATE JOIN syntax. But unfortunately Sqlite does not support [UPDATE](http://sqlite.org/lang_update.html) JOIN.

Luckily for you you have only a few thousand rows and that makes it possible to iterate through them and update each row individually.

```
raw_query = '''SELECT s.*, a.id as fkid 
            FROM myapp_song s 
            INNER JOIN myapp_artist a on s.temp_artist = a.name'''
for song in Song.objects.raw(raw_query)
    song.artist_id = s.fkid
    song.save()
```

This might take a few minutes to complete because you don't have an index on temp_artist and name. Take care to replace myapp with the actual name of your app.

**Edit1:**

Though Sqlite doesn't have update JOIN, it does allow you to SET a value with a subquery. So this will also work.

```
UPDATE myapp_song set artist_id = 
  (SELECT id from myapp_artist WHERE name = myapp_song.temp_artist)
```

type it in the sqlite console or GUI. Make sure to replace myapp with your own app name. **This will be very quick because it's a single query**. All other solutions including my alternative solution in this answer involve 10,000 queries.

**Edit 2**

If your Artist table is empty at the moment, before you do all this you will have to populate it, here is an easy query that does it

```
INSERT INTO stackoverflow_artist(name)
   SELECT distinct temp_artist from stackoverflow_song
```

note that you should have a unique index on Artist.name

Comment: If using the your second method, myapp_artist table is currently empty with no data and artist name field needs to be created first, so how would it SELECT id from myapp_artist at this point?

Comment: Oops there was a small error in the query. It needed a distinct. Also note the observation about unique

Comment: just out of curiosity, why was the other answer chosen when mine was the one that explained all the issued that you raised?

Comment: Oops thought the check meant it also worked. Didn't see that you could only choose one but yours was faster.

Comment: thanks. When an answer is good, it's customary to upvote (I will also upvote the other answer). But don;t worry it's not a big deal

Answer (score 2):

You can write a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/) that performs this logic for you. The docs provide good instructions on how to set it up. Your command code would look something like this:

```
# e.g., migrateauthors.py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from myapp import models

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Migrate authors from old schema'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for song in myapp.models.Song.objects.all():
            song.artist, _ = models.Artist.objects.get_or_create(name=song.temp_artist)
            song.save()
```

Then you simply run the management command with `manage.py migrateauthors`. Once this is done and verified you can remove the temporary field from your model.